# In unix -rwxrwxr-x+ what last + means?

Tags: unix, ls

I know rwx represent read write and execute, but I get confuse about the meaning of +. Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means your file has extended permissions called ACLs.

See [Access Control Lists](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-acls.html) for more details.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/227852/what-does-a-mean-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-from-ls-l